# Is GPS timestamp from the GPS signal or the device?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, gps

My Windows Phone app uses location tracking, and I am stamping the positions I use, with the system date and time.
This has worked well, but now there was a situation with a user, who had his date/time setup horribly wrong on his phone, meaning that the timestamps on his positions were all wrong.

So, I was looking into the [`Timestamp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geocoordinate.timestamp) property on the [`Geocoordinate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geocoordinate.aspx) instead, but my question is: Is that timestamp really from the GPS unit, or is it just the system (device) date/time of when the position was obtained?

The documentation on MSDN says it is:

> The system time at which the location was determined.

If that is the case I really don't see much use for it,  but has anyone tested or have experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

I have always interpreted this as the Systemtime but your question made me curios. So I tested this by experiment, switching off the set-time automatically and changing the the time somewhat will indeed change the timestamp of the Geocoordinate. While I have not found a good source to collaborate this my experiment makes me believe that your assessment is correct.

A way to go around this problem for your app could be to get the time from an online time service such as [timezonedb api](http://timezonedb.com/api) ?

Comment: Ok, thanks.
Unfortunately I cannot rely on internet connection while I collect positions. (It's a marine app for sailors, often well beyond cell coverage) :-)